# Get asp.net server control id which is changing dynamically after render into the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I created on server control with id "**ResultOutput**". this is a textbox. After that I added this control to visual webpart. I deployed into sharepoint site. After rendering the page if i see the ID of that textbox, id has been changed to **ct100_m_g_cb6c8826_a6e5_4169_a3ef_4bfc7dfb26c_ct100_ResultOutput**.
To retrieve id of the server control we can use in jquery like

`$('<%= ResultOutput.ClientID %>')`.

But in this case the id is changing, so jquery not able to find that id. To find whether in that modified id actual id is presented or not I used like `$("[id*=ResultOutput]").length`, it is giving value as 1. So finally we found that element. Now I want to assign some text into that textbox. I am unable to find the solution for this for which the id is changing dynamically.

If i give `$("[id*=ResultOutput]").id` it is giving me undefined. What is the way to catch that in jquery? and I want to place text in the textbox control.

Answer (score 1):

To get the id have to use the `attr('id')` in jquery.
`$("[id*=ResultOutput]").attr('id')` gives you the id. If you want to change the text in that textbox control then you have to use like below.

`var myboxid = $("[id*=ResultOutput]").attr('id');
$('#'+myboxid).val("yourvalue");`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery factory method usually ***returns the collection/array.***

So access it like below

```
  $("[id*=ResultOutput]")[0].id
```

Also i am not sure is ***missing #*** symbol in your id selector gives nothing. Please include and try again.

```
 $('#<%= ResultOutput.ClientID %>').
```

Comment: if I use `$('#<%= ResultOutput.ClientID %>')` it is not working. because id is changing dynamically.

Comment: The `<%= %>` expression's purpose is exactly to render dynamic data that changes. So no matter what the ID, as long as ResultOutput is not changed, this should work.